# adding notifications for 500 status errors on google stackdriver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

Although this is not a code related question, I was wondering if there is a way to add notifications to google cloud services, more specifically to the Stackdriver Trace service?

I wan't to add notifications when there are requests which end in 500 status code errors.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: see this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47080801/is-it-possible-to-trigger-notification-e-g-for-http-500-from-stackdriver-log I would like a better way. But, this works.