# Is it possible to trigger notification (e.g.- for HTTP 500) from Stackdriver log/monitoring?

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I have set up Stackdriver logging agents on Google Compute Engine VMs, and collecting logs from apache and some other sources. Is it possible to trigger a notification when a http 500 log is produced?

If parsing textPayload for notification is not an option, can it be done by modifying the fluentid configs to send in a specific label when it uploads a matching log?

Answer (score 1):

I think that a logging metric is your best bet.
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/charts-and-alerts#creating_a_simple_alerting_policy_on_a_counter_metric